# Bash alias a command with backtick/executable part (escape backticks)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have made a simple bash command to clear caches in Laravel:

```
for w in `php artisan | grep 'clear' | awk '{print $1;}'`; do php artisan $w; done
```

I would like to add this as an alias, e.g. I just do `laravel-cache`. I ran:

```
alias laravel-cache="for w in `php artisan | grep 'clear' | awk '{print $1;}'`; do php artisan $w; done"
```

thinking this would add an alias, but when running `alias` to see them, I found:

```
# alias
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias laravel-cache='for w in clear-compiled
auth:clear-resets
cache:clear
config:clear
route:clear
view:clear; do php artisan view:clear; done'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto
```

but obviously this didn't work:

```
# laravel-cache
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `auth:clear-resets
```

So, my question would be how do you escape the backtick (or executable part to execute when the alias is run and not when it is added)?

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the corrrect way to iterate over the output of a command.

Comment: @chepner: Good suggestion; I'm curious — when answering a question where does one draw the line and not "rewrite" the persons entire code basically from scratch? This has been somewhat of a dilemma which I'm not sure which side to take. On one hand maybe it's better to deal with the issue regarding the question itself, on the other if you do it "right" then you've re-written the entire thing most of the time.

Comment: @l'L'l I usually provide an answer using a `while` loop instead of the `for` loop, though I am not consistent in how I do so. Sometimes I provide a solutions showing both the `for` loop and the correct `while` loop, other times I only show the solution using the `while` loop. Either way, I reference the Bash FAQ link in may answer to provide the explanation for why `for` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably be creating a `function` instead of an `alias`:

**Single Line**

```
laravel-cache () { for w in $(php artisan | grep 'clear' | awk '{print $1}'); do php artisan "$w"; done ; }
```

**Formatted**

```
laravel-cache () { 
  for w in $(php artisan | grep 'clear' | awk '{print $1}') 
    do
      php artisan "$w"
  done ;
}
```

Generally whenever doing more than just changing the default options of the command (eg. piping to additional command(s)) it's recommended to use a function.

You can add this to your `~/.bash_profile` for example and then use it similarly to an alias. Once added to your profile simply source it and you should be ready to use the command:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```